# Convert some attribute value into element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an xml where the the node contains multiple attribute .Out of which I want 2 or 3 attributes to become  element and insert some extra attribute in the same element. Below  is the xml structure which i want to convert

```
      <Parent>
          <NODE attr1="INDEX" attr2="0" attr3="OFF" attr4="TRANSPARENT_MODE" attr5="HIGH" attr6="0" attr7="0" attr8="TIME">
            <value>0</value>
            <alias>Index 0</alias>

          </NODE >
  </Parent>
```

I want to transform this xml to

```
 <Parent>
              <NODE  attr2="0" attr3="OFF" attr4="TRANSPARENT_MODE"  attr6="0"  attr8="TIME">
               <attr1 value="INDEX">
               <attr5 value="HIGH">
              <attr7 value="0">
                <value>0</value>
                <alias>Index 0</alias>

              </NODE >
      </Parent>
```

So as I had shown I only want 3 attribute i.e attr1 attr5 and attr7 to be element and other to stay as it is.For this I tried below xslt styling

```
<xsl:template match="Parent/NODE/@attr1">
<attr1>
<xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
</attr1>
</xsl:template>
```

But after doing this for 3 attributes other attributes are not coming in transformed xml. Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Hard to tell without the rest of your XSLT code, but are you sure you're copying the other attributes into the NODE ?

Comment: This is probably because your XSLT adds the `attr1` element before copying across any existing attributes you want to stay as an attributes. This is considered an error according to the spec (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes). As mentioned in that link, your XSLT processor must be taking the option of ignoring the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfect because it repeats the condition for inclusion two times, but it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NODE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*[name()!='attr1' and name()!='attr3']">
                <xsl:copy />
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*[name()='attr1' or name()='attr3']">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="value" select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltransform.net/jxDigTS/1